# What to do when package version cannot be found however I can see it on nuget.org?

Tags: nuget

I have a project where I need `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Common.Contracts`. According to [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Common.Contracts/) there is a `15.114.0-preview` package. But, Visual Studio says that there is no package like this.

I clean all local cache and doesn't help.

How can I solve it? Generally, how much time is needed for a package to go through the spreading process if there is any?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking at the wrong package in Visual Studio Package manager window.

Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Common.**Contracts** has latest version as **15.114.0-preview**

while Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Common has latest version as **15.112.1**

Hope this helps.

-AG.